# How can I produce an image array as the average of multiple image arrays?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to create the average heatmap from multiple heatmaps.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from scipy import misc

f1 = misc.imread('heatmap1.png')
f2 = misc.imread('heatmap2.png')
f3 = misc.imread('heatmap3.png')
f_avg=np.average([f1,f2,f3],axis=0)
plt.imshow(f_avg)
plt.show()
```

This is heatmap1.png:

[image: This is 'heatmap1']

This is the result of averaging the 3 heatmaps:

[image]

It looks like this is not the way to compute the avg of color arrays.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What's your expected output? And you probably should make your images available to us. (and is this really a mathematically sound approach?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `plt.imshow(f_avg.astype(np.uint8))` so that `imshow` can detect that this is an image and not arbitrary floating-point data. I don't have access to all three of your images, but if I test using `f1` three times, or with random noise images, this change makes the code behave as I would expect (where it doesn't without the change).

Also beware that these image arrays have RGB values and an alpha value that are all getting averaged - the average of these three images won't necessarily be the same as the heatmap you'd get with all of the data included (but it's a good rough estimate, if that's all you have access to).